# Laravel can't upgrade from 5.7 to 7.0, composer compatibility failures

Tags: laravel, composer-php, upgrade, laravel-7

I'm trying to update laravel from 5.7 to 7 but no matter what package I try to update I composer keeps failing.

I've also tried to remove the vendor file from my project and the composer-lock.json, but no succes there as well.

How can I upgrade my current laravel app from 5.7 to 7

**command line failure**

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update --with-dependencies  

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - barryvdh/laravel-cors v0.11.2 requires illuminate/support 5.5.x|5.6.x|5.7.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.28, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.9 requires nesbot/carbon ^1.26.3 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.26.3, 1.26.4, 1.26.5, 1.26.6, 1.27.0, 1.28.0, 1.29.0, 1.29.1, 1.29.2, 1.30.0, 1.31.0, 1.31.1, 1.32.0, 1.33.0, 1.34.0, 1.34.1, 1.34.2, 1.34.3, 1.34.4, 1.35.0, 1.35.1, 1.36.0, 1.36.1, 1.36.2, 1.37.0, 1.37.1, 1.38.0, 1.38.1, 1.38.2, 1.38.3, 1.38.4, 1.39.0, 1.39.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4.6",
        "alymosul/laravel-exponent-push-notifications": "^2.1",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.2",
        "beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.1",
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "1.5",
        "illuminate/config": "^7.0",
        "illuminate/validation": "^7.27",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.24",
        "laravel/passport": "^7.5",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.2",
        "mollie/laravel-mollie": "2.0",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^2.39.1",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^4.1",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5",
        "sven/artisan-view": "^3.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: dont upgrade to directly from 5.7 to 7..go step wise first try to upgrade from 5.7 to 6 then upgrade to 7.....then you can easily find the problem...

Comment: It's likely that you have multiple packages in use that have specific Laravel compatibility requirements. For example, in the error you posted, `barryvdh/laravel-cors` requires Laravel 5.x or 6.x, not 7.

Comment: @AkenRoberts Hmm, so I should remove those packages? I guess the best is to indeed slowley upgrade ?

Comment: `barryvdh/laravel-cors` above version 1.0.1 supports Laravel 7, you need to upgrade your dependencies and (most importantly) update your code to work with the new versions since they are not backwards compatible

Comment: What way can I find out what packages are compatible or what package I also need to update?

Answer (score -1):

in your composer.json you have "laravel/framework": "^7.24".

to solve the issue you need to add those 2 :
illuminate/support
nesbot/carbon

This is what composer is saying.

Comment: No, it's not saying that, it's saying that barryvdh/laravel-cors v0.11.2 can't be installed with Laravel 7, meaning that he needs to use a compatible version of barryvdh/laravel-cors with Laravel 7

Comment: ah i see, you are using an old version of laravel-cors

Comment: composer remove barryvdh/laravel-cors
composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: try this or simply edit your composer.json and put the last version which is compatibe with laravel 7 you can have the last version from packagist

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should any of these two packages be required now?